# Converting to (not from) ipython Notebook format

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

IPython Notebook comes with [`nbconvert`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/notebook/nbconvert.html), which can *export* notebooks to other formats.  But how do I convert text in the opposite direction? I ask because I already have materials, and a good workflow, in a different format, but I would like to take advantage of Notebook's interactive environment.

A likely solution: A notebook can be created by importing a `.py` file, and the documentation states that when `nbconvert` exports a notebook as a python script, it embeds directives in comments that can be used to recreate the notebook. But the information comes with [a disclaimer](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/notebook/notebook.html#importing-py-files) about the limitations of this method, and the accepted format is not documented anywhere that I could find. (A sample is shown, oddly enough, in the section describing notebook's [JSON format](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/notebook/nbconvert.html#notebook-json-file-format)). Can anyone provide more information, or a better alternative?

**Edit (1 March 2016):** The accepted answer no longer works, because for some reason this input format is not supported by version 4 of the Notebook API.  **I have added [a self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35720002/699305)** showing how to import a notebook with the current (v4) API. (I am not un-accepting the current answer, since it solved my problem at the time and pointed me to the resources I used in my self-answer.)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The following works for IPython 3, but not IPython 4.

The IPython API has functions for reading and writing notebook files. You should use this API and not create JSON directly. For example, the following code snippet converts a script `test.py` into a notebook `test.ipynb`.

```
import IPython.nbformat.current as nbf
nb = nbf.read(open('test.py', 'r'), 'py')
nbf.write(nb, open('test.ipynb', 'w'), 'ipynb')
```

Regarding the format of the .py file understood by nbf.read it is best to simply look into the parser class IPython.nbformat.v3.nbpy.PyReader. The code can be found here (it is not very large):

<strike>https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/jupyter_nbformat/v3/nbpy.py</strike>

**Edit:** This answer was originally written for IPyhton 3. I don't know how to do this properly with IPython 4. Here is an updated version of the link above, pointing to the version of `nbpy.py` from the IPython 3.2.1 release:

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/rel-3.2.1/IPython/nbformat/v3/nbpy.py

Basically you use special comments such as `# <codecell>` or `# <markdowncell>` to separate the individual cells. Look at the `line.startswith` statements in `PyReader.to_notebook` for a complete list.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. I had no plans to generate JSON directly, but rather to generate python with the right directives and let notebook import it; your code makes it possible to do this automatically rather than manually. But the question remains: what notebook directives can the python script contain?

Comment: @alexis I've now added some additional notes about the special directives in .py notebook files.

Comment: Thanks! That and the sample `.py` file I linked to in my question seem like a sufficient reference. For completeness, the current directives are `<nbformat>` (3.0), `<codecell>, <htmlcell>, <markdowncell>, <rawcell>`, and `<headincell level=N>`. (I'm ignoring the deprecated `<plaintextcell>`.)

Comment: Sorry but I'm re-opening the question, because I can't get this to work yet! I can't open any `.py` file in notebook, as I should be able to. I've opened [a separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23303402/699305) about it because I suspect the problem might be with my installation, but if you have any ideas I'd appreciate them.

Comment: @alexis I think the notebook application can only open .ipynb, not .py files. How did you "export" the .py files from notebook? Was it with "File->Downalod as"? I only have IPython 1.2.1 here at the moment and this version creates files with the `<...>` tags. So I'm afraid I don't have any additional expertise to offer..

Comment: At least on my installation, this `import` statement gives `UserWarning: IPython.nbformat.current is deprecated.`

Comment: That link appears dead now, is there an alternative?

Comment: @Alex, how did that work for you? As far as I can tell, the python import/export format has been dropped from notebook format v.4-- the tokens "codecell" and "markdowncell" don't even appear in the source. I've resorted to reading python with a v3 notebook reader, then saving as v4.

Comment: @alexis yes I think you're right, I couldn't see any of that code in v4 either. I had to resort to converting it to a v3 notebook, opening it and letting IPython convert it to v4 like you. It is by no means a clean solution, but seems to work.

Comment: @Alex, I have added [a self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35720002/699305) showing how to import notebooks and save them in v4 format immediately. (Also how to get around a nasty bug...)

Answer (score 45):

Since the code in the accepted answer does not work anymore, I have added this self-answer that shows how to import into a notebook with the current (`v4`) API.

### Input format

Versions 2 and 3 of the IPython Notebook API can import a python script with special structuring comments, and break it up into cells as desired.  Here's a sample input file (original documentation [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/notebook/nbconvert.html#notebook-json-file-format)). The first two lines are ignored, and optional. (In fact, the reader will ignore `coding:` and `<nbformat>` lines anywhere in the file.)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# <nbformat>3.0</nbformat>

# <markdowncell>

# The simplest notebook. Markdown cells are embedded in comments, 
# so the file is a valid `python` script. 
# Be sure to **leave a space** after the comment character!

# <codecell>

print("Hello, IPython")

# <rawcell>

# Raw cell contents are not formatted as markdown
```

(The API also accepts the obsolete directives `<htmlcell>` and `<headingcell level=...>`, which are immediately transformed to other types.)

#### How to import it

For some reason, this format is not supported by version 4 of the Notebook API. It's still a nice format, so it's worth the trouble to support it by importing into version 3 and upgrading. *In principle* it's just two lines of code, plus i/o:

```
from IPython.nbformat import v3, v4

with open("input-file.py") as fpin:
    text = fpin.read()

nbook = v3.reads_py(text)
nbook = v4.upgrade(nbook)  # Upgrade v3 to v4

jsonform = v4.writes(nbook) + "\n"
with open("output-file.ipynb", "w") as fpout:
    fpout.write(jsonform)
```

But not so fast! In fact, the notebook API has a nasty bug: If the last cell in the input is a markdown cell, `v3.reads_py()` will lose it. The simplest work-around is to tack on a bogus `<markdown>` cell at the end: The bug will delete it, and everyone is happy. So do the following before you pass `text` to `v3.reads_py()`:

```
text += """
# <markdowncell>

# If you can read this, reads_py() is no longer broken! 
"""
```

Comment: Nice. Check also [this script](https://github.com/yianni/py2ipynb) I've written that works with spyder and pycharm cell markers plus some extra candies for slide making. PS: Might want to this to your edit (and i think you meant 2016) :)

Comment: Oops! Yeah indeed it's 2016 :-)

Comment: Hmm tried quickly your script above but getting an error message `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`. That is on the `fpout.write` statement.

Comment: Using python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 2.4.1 (x86_64), jupyter 4.0.6 and notebook 4.1.0. What about you?

Comment: Oops! I forgot a call to `v4.writes()`, which generates json. Fixed now, thanks for catching it!

Comment: Great. Can I integrate your code to my script (with appropriate credit) for completeness?

Comment: Awesome. Will do so when I get a chance. Shouldn't take long. Out of curiosity, are there any docs for the tags like `# <codecell>`,  `# <markdowncell>`, etc. Websearch didn't give me anything useful.

Comment: The only place I've found a list of the cell types is the source (see the accepted answer for the link). To see which cells are ignored or obsolete, see there and also skip over to `v4/convert.py`.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Included your code on master branch :).

Comment: Thank you for posting this! I've added a semi-generic version of it, with the adjustment, and a simple unittest: [script](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/b337b1a/python/jupyter/nb_py_stuff/convert.py) | [test](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/b337b1a/python/jupyter/nb_py_stuff/convert_test.sh)

Answer (score 44):

very old question, i know. but there is [`jupytext`](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) (also available on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/jupytext/)) that can convert from `ipynb` to several formats and back.

when `jupytext` is installed you can use

```
$ jupytext --to notebook test.py
```

in order to generate `test.ipynb`.

`jupytext` has a lot more interesting features that can come in handy when working with notebooks.

---

here is [a more recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55919667/how-to-convert-a-python-script-with-cell-delimiters-to-a-jupyter-notebook) on that topic.

Comment: Nice to know, thanks for the update! I'll check it out.

Comment: @alexis, could you add this answer to the text your question? Because it really works in fall 2019 and it is absolutely hassle free.

Answer (score 11):

Python code example how to build IPython notebook V4:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from base64 import encodestring

from IPython.nbformat.v4.nbbase import (
    new_code_cell, new_markdown_cell, new_notebook,
    new_output, new_raw_cell
)

# some random base64-encoded *text*
png = encodestring(os.urandom(5)).decode('ascii')
jpeg = encodestring(os.urandom(6)).decode('ascii')

cells = []
cells.append(new_markdown_cell(
    source='Some NumPy Examples',
))


cells.append(new_code_cell(
    source='import numpy',
    execution_count=1,
))

cells.append(new_markdown_cell(
    source='A random array',
))

cells.append(new_raw_cell(
    source='A random array',
))

cells.append(new_markdown_cell(
    source=u'## My Heading',
))

cells.append(new_code_cell(
    source='a = numpy.random.rand(100)',
    execution_count=2,
))
cells.append(new_code_cell(
    source='a = 10\nb = 5\n',
    execution_count=3,
))
cells.append(new_code_cell(
    source='a = 10\nb = 5',
    execution_count=4,
))

cells.append(new_code_cell(
    source=u'print "ünîcødé"',
    execution_count=3,
    outputs=[new_output(
        output_type=u'execute_result',
        data={
            'text/plain': u'<array a>',
            'text/html': u'The HTML rep',
            'text/latex': u'$a$',
            'image/png': png,
            'image/jpeg': jpeg,
            'image/svg+xml': u'<svg>',
            'application/json': {
                'key': 'value'
            },
            'application/javascript': u'var i=0;'
        },
        execution_count=3
    ),new_output(
        output_type=u'display_data',
        data={
            'text/plain': u'<array a>',
            'text/html': u'The HTML rep',
            'text/latex': u'$a$',
            'image/png': png,
            'image/jpeg': jpeg,
            'image/svg+xml': u'<svg>',
            'application/json': {
                'key': 'value'
            },
            'application/javascript': u'var i=0;'
        },
    ),new_output(
        output_type=u'error',
        ename=u'NameError',
        evalue=u'NameError was here',
        traceback=[u'frame 0', u'frame 1', u'frame 2']
    ),new_output(
        output_type=u'stream',
        text='foo\rbar\r\n'
    ),new_output(
        output_type=u'stream',
        name='stderr',
        text='\rfoo\rbar\n'
    )]
))

nb0 = new_notebook(cells=cells,
    metadata={
        'language': 'python',
    }
)

import IPython.nbformat as nbf
import codecs
f = codecs.open('test.ipynb', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
nbf.write(nb0, f, 4)
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. It doesn't really fit the question (importing a file), but it could be useful to other aspiring notebook hackers.

Answer (score 11):

Hope I'm not too late.

I just published a Python package on PyPI called **p2j**. This package creates a Jupyter notebook `.ipynb` from a Python source code `.py`.

```bash
pip install p2j
p2j script.py
```

Example of a Jupyter notebook generated from a `.py` file:

[image: Example of .ipynb generated from a .py file]

PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/p2j/

GitHub: https://github.com/remykarem/python2jupyter

Comment: Thanks for the report. Did you think about headings, raw cells, comments that should remain python comments, and other notebook format features? There's no mention of them in your github page. Also, it would be smart to add special handling for emacs directives and the like (`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` ), since you use them yourself. Finally, please indicate whether you are using the jupyter api or coding the json generation yourself.

Comment: Hi @alexis. I've just updated the readme on my GitHub repo, and included the directives. Hopefully that would answer your first question. For your last question, I'm coding the JSON generation by myself.

Comment: you're not too late for us future readers! :-) I noticed that I had to delete a lot of white space (blank lines) and hit "run" many times to step through, but I got some nice results. Unfortunately my plot is interactive using [widgets](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/widgets_api.html) and my notebook only shows an image of the plot not a real, interactive one. I guess I'll have to research that myself and so some post-modification of the converted notebook [Jupyter Notebook: interactive plot with widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44329068/3904031)

Answer (score 7):

Given the example by Volodimir Kopey, I put together a bare-bones script to convert a .py obtained by exporting from a .ipynb back into a V4 .ipynb.

I hacked this script together when I edited (in a proper IDE) a .py I had exported from a Notebook and I wanted to go back to Notebook to run it cell by cell.

The script handles only code cells. The exported .py does not contain much else, anyway.

```
import nbformat
from nbformat.v4 import new_code_cell,new_notebook

import codecs

sourceFile = "changeMe.py"     # <<<< change
destFile = "changeMe.ipynb"    # <<<< change


def parsePy(fn):
    """ Generator that parses a .py file exported from a IPython notebook and
extracts code cells (whatever is between occurrences of "In[*]:").
Returns a string containing one or more lines
"""
    with open(fn,"r") as f:
        lines = []
        for l in f:
            l1 = l.strip()
            if l1.startswith('# In[') and l1.endswith(']:') and lines:
                yield "".join(lines)
                lines = []
                continue
            lines.append(l)
        if lines:
            yield "".join(lines)

# Create the code cells by parsing the file in input
cells = []
for c in parsePy(sourceFile):
    cells.append(new_code_cell(source=c))

# This creates a V4 Notebook with the code cells extracted above
nb0 = new_notebook(cells=cells,
                   metadata={'language': 'python',})

with codecs.open(destFile, encoding='utf-8', mode='w') as f:
    nbformat.write(nb0, f, 4)
```

No guarantees, but it worked for me

Comment: Thanks! I already have a whole toolchain using the `# <...cell>` format, but your solution could be useful to others-- especially since your format is generated when Notebook exports. Could you document it better (`parsePy` returns _lists_ of lines? One per cell? How can you tell markup from code cells?) and add a sample input file to the answer text?

Answer (score 5):

I wrote an extension for vscode that might help. It converts the python files to ipython notebooks. It's in early stages so if any error occurs, feel free to submit an issue.

[Jupyter Notebook Converter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yigitozgumus.NbConverter)

Answer (score 4):

Took the liberty of taking and modifying the code of P.Toccateli and alexis so that it will also work with pycharm and spyder like cell markers and released it on [github](https://github.com/yianni/py2ipynb).

Comment: Thanks. Should be useful for anyone working with these formats.

Answer (score 1):

Some improvement to @p-toccaceli answer.
Now, it also restores markdown cells. Additionally, it trims empty hanging lines for each cell.

```
    import nbformat
    from nbformat.v4 import new_code_cell,new_markdown_cell,new_notebook

    import codecs

    sourceFile = "changeMe.py"     # <<<< change
    destFile = "changeMe.ipynb"    # <<<< change


    def parsePy(fn):
        """ Generator that parses a .py file exported from a IPython notebook and
    extracts code cells (whatever is between occurrences of "In[*]:").
    Returns a string containing one or more lines
    """
        with open(fn,"r") as f:
            lines = []
            for l in f:
                l1 = l.strip()
                if l1.startswith('# In[') and l1.endswith(']:') and lines:
                    yield ("".join(lines).strip(), 0)
                    lines = []
                    continue
                elif l1.startswith('# ') and l1[2:].startswith('#') and lines:
                    yield ("".join(lines).strip(), 0)

                    yield (l1[2:].strip(), 1)
                    lines = []
                    continue
                lines.append(l)
            if lines:
                yield ("".join(lines).strip(), 0)

    # Create the code cells by parsing the file in input
    cells = []
    for c, code in parsePy(sourceFile):
        if len(c) == 0:
            continue
        if code == 0:
            cells.append(new_code_cell(source=c))
        elif code == 1:
            cells.append(new_markdown_cell(source=c))

    # This creates a V4 Notebook with the code cells extracted above
    nb0 = new_notebook(cells=cells,
                       metadata={'language': 'python',})

    with codecs.open(destFile, encoding='utf-8', mode='w') as f:
        nbformat.write(nb0, f, 4)
```

Comment: Note that there is already an accepted answer to this question. Please [edit] your answer to ensure that it improves upon other answers already present in this question.
While it might answer the question, just adding some code does not help OP or future community members understand the issue or solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the script py2nb from https://github.com/sklam/py2nb

You will have to use a certain syntax for your *.py but it's rather simple to use (look at the example in the 'samples' folder)

Comment: What would be the benefit of this ad hoc solution (with an ad hoc format and unknown bugs and limitations), instead of the format supported by notebook itself?