# Cannot import .py file to ipython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

With apologies in advance for the "I can't get it to work" question: How should I load a `.py` file into ipython notebook? I want to convert python code to notebooks (first simple scripts and later scripts that include `nbconvert` directives [embedded as comments](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/notebook/nbconvert.html#notebook-json-file-format)-- see bottom of the linked file.)

Perhaps I'm doing it wrong, but perhaps there's something wrong with my set-up. When I drag a `.py` file to the Notebook's file list, I get the message

> Invalid file type: Uploaded notebooks must be `.ipynb` files.

I even tried changing the extension to `.ipynb` (keeping the python script unmodified); reasonably enough, I got an error:

> Error loading notebook: Bad request

Any idea what's going wrong?

System information: I'm on OS X (10.8, Mountain Lion), using Firefox 28.0 and  Anaconda 1.9.2 (x86_64), which supplies python 2.7.6 and ipython 2.0. Anaconda is not on the default PATH; I add it in a bash session from which I then launch notebook with `ipython notebook`, and I'm able to open and edit `.ipynb` files normally in the browser.

But I do get some curious behavior: 
**When exporting from notebook** as a `.py` file, I don't get the control comments documented [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/notebook/nbconvert.html#notebook-json-file-format) but a simpler format, without version number:

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[ ]:

print "This is a slide"

## Top-level title 

### Second-level heading 

#### Third-level heading

# This is some `markdown` text. 
# 
# And some more here.
```

Any idea what's going on here?

The same format is generated by `ipython nbconvert`. However, if I start the notebook server with `ipython notebook --script` (which exports the notebook as a python script every time it is saved), the result contains the `nbconvert` directives we need to convert back to a notebook!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting to (not from) ipython Notebook format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292242/converting-to-not-from-ipython-notebook-format)

Comment: @Cristian, the questions are related but they're not duplicates; that's why I asked both of them. The *answer* to this one is that there's no way to do it in the GUI, which is the only reason the other question becomes relevant.

Comment: Ok, I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why notebook doesn't support this natively, but I've concluded that the answer is: It can't be done from the command line or notebook GUI.

Control comments like `<markdowncell>` can only be interpreted by accessing notebook's API through python, as shown by @CliffordVienna in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23292713/699305) to my related question.

```py
import IPython.nbformat.current as nbf
nb = nbf.read(open('test.py', 'r'), 'py')
nbf.write(nb, open('test.ipynb', 'w'), 'ipynb')
```

**Edit:** The above method does not work with the current version (`v4`) of the Notebook API, so I have added [this self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35720002/699305) to show how it's done.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem.
This post helped:
[How to load/edit/run/save text files (.py) into an IPython notebook cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034373/is-there-a-way-to-import-py-file-into-the-cell-of-an-ipython-notebook-cell-so-t)

Basically, we just have to use the following command in the cell. And the .py file has to be in the same directory.

```
%load filename.py
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful feature to know about but not what I needed. I've solved the problem in the meantime, I should have self-answered sooner.

Answer (score -2):

If you only need to *import* a local file, first use:

sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

to place the .pynb file's directory in sys.path, and then import the local file.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but do you know what an ipython _notebook_ is? `sys.path` is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Actuallly, it is relevant. If the python file is in a different directory, you need to use sys.path. For your specific case, where the file is in the same directory, you don't need to use sys.path.