# How can I edit Jupyter/IPython notebooks as text files?

Tags: ipython, knitr, jupyter

I would like to use Jupyter/IPython notebooks for writing reports, but I would prefer to avoid the browser interface.  Instead, I would like to be able to write the notebook in some text-based format, e.g. markdown, and export the notebook afterwards.  Essentially I would like to use Jupyter in a Knitr-esque workflow.  Is this currently possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. If you want to write Ipython scripts in IDE try to use the PyCharm. But if you want to convert *.py to *.ipynb please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303402/cannot-import-py-file-to-ipython-notebook .

Answer (score 2):

[Jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) does exactly this. It lets you edit scripts or markdown and auto-sync to Jupyter Notebooks and other formats.

Answer (score 1):

To get a Knitr-esque flow you might look into the Atom plugin, [hydrogen](https://atom.io/packages/hydrogen). From what I understand it allows you to execute code inline using your installed Jupyter kernels. Of course, this would only work in Atom.

Answer (score 1):

You can write reports in Markdown and then convert them into Jupyter notebooks with `notedown`:

- https://github.com/aaren/notedown

That's the closest option to `knitr`. It also supports r-markdown (`.Rmd`) conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter Notebooks are stored as json. If you are comfortable reading the raw JSON, simply open the notebook file in your favorite text editor.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned `knitr`, so at least some of your code is probably R.  If so, take a look at the RStudio notebooks preview at http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html.  It stores the notebook in plain text as an Rmd file, but expands it to HTML for display.  You can also recover the plain text from the HTML.  I don't know how good the Python support would be, though.