# Cannot import module in Jupyter Notebook (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I want to import a user-defined module `utils.py` in Jupyter Notebook. This should be a trivial task, but for some reason it fails.

Project structure:

```
myapp/data/test.csv
myapp/packages/utils.py
myapp/test.ipynb
```

The file `utils.py` contains many functions, e.g. `def myfunc():...`.

In `test.ipynb` I tried `from packages import utils`. Also I tried to put `utils.py` into the same folder as `test.ipynb` and run `import utils`. But all the time it fails with one of these two errors:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'utils' ModuleNotFoundError: No module
>   named 'utils'

The command `sys.executable` executed from the notebook gives me a correct path to python.exe.

It's weird because I can import data without any issues as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data/test.csv", sep=";")
```

How can I check what causes this problem?

Comment: Please check if [this answer from another stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303402/cannot-import-py-file-to-ipython-notebook) would be useful.

Comment: @gireesh4manu: It helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from packages.utils import *
```

It worked for me, so I hope it works for you aswell.

Comment: Thank you, but it gave me the same error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packages.utils". I think that there is some issue with sys.paths but I don't know how to validate it.

Comment: Have you tried to restart your kernel? It might not see the new import.

Comment: Importing with * works but I wonder why cannot I simply import by name