# Is there a way to create a .ipynb from a .py file command line?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to create a .ipynb from a .py file command line?

Why I would want to do this: I want to refactore some code using a text editor. My ipynb file is on a server, and it is way easier to transfer a .py file (generated by running ipython notebook with --script) that is tracked on a version control system (git) than ipynb.

Ideally I want to do the following:

- the Notebook is running with `--script`, so I have a .py file
- commit the new version of the file, push from the server and pull on my machine
- pull from my machine
- edit on my machine
- commit, push from my machine and pull from the server
- create the .ipynb file from the new .py file and replace the old one

And I can't find any way to start on the server an iPython Notebook from a py file that is on the server.

Sure, I can add the .ipynb to git, but there are good reasons not to do that. I could also send files using ftps, but since it is something I do rather often I'd like to find a better solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting to (not from) ipython Notebook format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292242)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it is covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23292713/3025981. I reproduce the snipped here:

```py
import IPython.nbformat.current as nbf
nb = nbf.read(open('test.py', 'r'), 'py')
nbf.write(nb, open('test.ipynb', 'w'), 'ipynb')
```

Comment: @BhargavRao, actually, I can just copy-paste the answer from the link, but I think that this question can be also marked as a dupe of the question I refer to. However, I'm not sure...

Answer (score 4):

From https://pypi.org/project/ipynb-py-convert/

```
pip install ipynb-py-convert
```

Example

```
ipynb-py-convert examples/plot.py examples/plot.ipynb
```

or

```
ipynb-py-convert examples/plot.ipynb examples/plot.py
```