# Jupyter is crashing while opening a notebook, what are my possible options?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython

I have an iPython notebook that I used to use with Jupyter Notebook. Suddenly I found that when I open this particular notebook with Jupyter (Notebook or Lab), the window becomes unresponsive and it crashes after 30 sec or so. Sometimes it shows MathJax is loading.

I have tried opening this in completely separate Conda environments (even in different computers) but face the same issue. This leads me to believe that I did something wrong (possibly with MathJax) with this notebook last time.

I want to copy the important codes from this notebook. What are my options? Can I read it in some sort of text mode just to copy the codes to a fresh notebook?

Comment: Your post lacks some details needed to advise you best. For example, how large is the `.ipynb` file? Does it include any large output? Do you store it in unrun form? If the size is the issue, you may want to try programmatically cleaning it first, see my advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74394583/8508004). Along the lines of Techionik's LTd suggestion to grab the code by hand with a coding text editor (VS Code works, but nothing else Microsoft in the name as it usually adds hidden characters and codes; other options are Sublime Text or Atom, etc.), you may want to programmatically...

Comment: <continued> try converting the `.ipynb` file, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73625066/8508004) for some ideas of how to do that. I like jupytext as a possible idea. You could then paste that code back in a new notebook. It may mess up some of the magic code and you'll have to convert that back. Another programmatic idea is to use nbformat. I don't have an exact example for this right now, but you can see some code at links [highlighted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74379308/8508004). You can honestly use it to collect the contents of cells. You can limit it to the code...

Comment: <continued>  in the cells even. You can also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71244733/8508004) about copying cells to a new notebook programmatically. You can add conditionals to only get what you want, too, such as code cells as nbformat has the concert of cell types baked in. This is all dependent on your file not being so corrupt as to not allowing nbformat to read it in in the first place. I'm basically saying Techionik LTd's idea is the most direct, but you may want to try and attempt to automate doing it and getting cleaner code at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script prints the code blocks properly (using `nbformat`):

```
import nbformat

def extract_code_from_notebook(notebook_path):
    with open(notebook_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        notebook = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)

    code_cells = [cell['source'] for cell in notebook['cells'] if cell['cell_type'] == 'code']

    return code_cells

notebook_path = 'notebook_name.ipynb'

try:
    extracted_code = extract_code_from_notebook(notebook_path)
    for i, code_cell in enumerate(extracted_code, start=1):
        print(f"Code Cell {i}:\n{code_cell}\n{'='*30}\n")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

Comment: So your notebooks weren't corrupted to the point that nbformat wouldn't open them? That is fortunate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you open your notebook in Notepad of any other text editor just open notepad and open your .ipynb file in it. Then you can copy your code.

Comment: You may want to point out that the original poster may need to clean up the escaping and line breaks to do this by hand.