# Working with ipywidgets and images

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

I can see an image, but I made a function to make changes to the array of that image (called `next_step`) and I want to see changes of that image trough ipywidgets while I control the parameters, but the problem is that the image is displayed multiple times while I would like to refresh it only.

[image]

[image]

This is the code:

```
def blur(t, c):
    steps = int(t / delta_t)

    sol = []

    sol.append(image)

    for i in range(steps):
        sol.append(next_step(sol[-1], c))

    clear_output()
    plt.imshow(sol[-1])
```

And the other one:

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
from ipywidgets import widgets

interact(blur, t=widgets.FloatSlider(min=t_min, max=t_max, step=delta_t), c=widgets.FloatSlider(min=0.1, max=1, step=0.1))
```

How can I update/refresh the image instead of printing it several times with ipywidgets?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329068/jupyter-notebook-interactive-plot-with-widgets) seems very much the same. The two solutions there are to eithe add `plt.show()` in the updating function or use the `%matplotlib notebook` backend.

Comment: Thanks! Adding `plt.show()` worked!

Comment: @PatricioSard Please show your function `next_step`