# ipywidgets interactive with plotly doesn't produce a plot

Tags: python, plotly, google-colaboratory, ipywidgets

I'm using GoogleColab. I'm trying to use interactive widgets with python plotly.
A function for produce a simple plotly just works:

```
from ipywidgets import interactive
import plotly.express as px

def g(x,y):
    fig = px.scatter(x=df[x], y=df[y])
    fig.show()

g('a','b')
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vuYk.png)

But when I try to involve interactive widgets, the output comes with the widgets but without the plot:

```
def g(x,y):
    fig = px.scatter(x=df[x], y=df[y])
    fig.show()

interactive_plot = interactive(g, x=columns, y=columns)
interactive_plot
```

[interactive output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5604.png)

When I change the library back to matplotlib it works well, as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693764/remove-past-matplotlib-plots-in-the-same-cell-in-jupyter-notebook-involving-inte/45694414#45694414). However, I have to use plotly because of their 'hovering' feature, which is truly convenient.