# How to convert a python script with cell delimiters to a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, converters

I mostly use Spyder for my data analysis and am quite satisfied with it. There you can use the cell functionality of Jupyter Notebooks in normal python scripts using `# %%` to delimit individual code cells (and also execute blocks). The same thing is also possible in Atom with Hydrogen.

What I am looking for is a way to convert these scripts into a jupyter notebook, automaticlally splitting cells at each `# %%`. The notebook I would use to document, explain and share my workflow by inserting some markdown and possibly saving as pdf or html.

Can the conversion be done automatically? Is this perhaps doable with `nbconvert`? (I only use it the other way around: jupyter -> python)

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53387906/4954037) may help.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Didn't find a question like this before. Feel free to close.

Comment: posted the answer here as the accepted answer to the other question is different and my answer has very low priority...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

there is [`jupytext`](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) (also available on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/jupytext/)) that can convert from `ipynb` to several formats and back.

when `jupytext` is installed you can use

```
$ jupytext --to notebook test.py
```

in order to generate `test.ipynb`.

`jupytext` has a lot more interesting features that can come in handy when working with notebooks.

Comment: For anyone wondering, I checked this answer and it automatically detects the `# %%` delimiters for cells.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer. Also [this](https://github.com/gatsoulis/py2ipynb) I have written a while ago (I am afraid I no longer maintain it) with references from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292242/converting-to-not-from-ipython-notebook-format) might still be working and be of use to you.

Here the [example](https://github.com/gatsoulis/py2ipynb/blob/master/examples/example_spyderlike.py) for spyder-like cell markers.