# How to work with .ipynb files without launching the Jupyter Notebook server?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I'm starting to work more with Jupyter notebooks, and am really starting to like it. However, I find it difficult to use it with my particular setup.

I have a workstation for running all the notebooks, but for a large part of my day I'm on-the-go with a space-constrained laptop with no power outlets. I'd like to be able to edit (but not run) these notebooks without installing and running the full Jupyter server backend, which I imagine would suck up a lot of power.

My question is: Is it possible for me to edit (and not run) notebooks without running the Jupyter server?

Comment: What are the specs on your laptop?  The `jupyter` server isn't any more demanding on memory than `ipython` console mode.  I use a refurbished business desktop.

Answer (score 5):

You could use one of the following options

#### 1. ipynb-py-convert

With this module you can do a conversion from .py to .ipynb and vice-versa:

```
ipynb-py-convert ~/name_of_notebook.ipynb ~/name_of_notebook.py
```

where according to the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/ipynb-py-convert/) the cells are left as they are. To get  back a jupyter notebook

```
ipynb-py-convert ~/name_of_notebook.py ~/name_of_notebook.ipynb
```

#### 2. Ipython

However, you could also do a conversion to .py when you want to work it with an editor like VS Code or Sublime Text after you have download your .ipynb file with [ipython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/1.x/interactive/nbconvert.html):

```
ipython nbconvert --to python name_of_your_notebook.ipynb
```

Comment: Jupytext can do similar conversions from notebook to script and back again, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53387906/8508004).

Answer (score 1):

As I was asking this question, I had [opened the notebook locally in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support), but the preview was just the raw text representation of the notebook, so I had assumed that it needed the backend to run.

However, I was about to press submit on the question when I checked back in on it, and the notebook showed up just fine. So one solution is to open it in VS Code and wait a little bit.