# converting from .py to .ipynb

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, file-conversion

I wrote a juypter notebook that has been converted to .py somehow. I would like it back in the original format. Does anyone know how to do that?

There is a previous stack overflow question about this, but the solution doesn't work for me. [Converting to (not from) ipython Notebook format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292242/converting-to-not-from-ipython-notebook-format)

The below is an example of what the code looks like now. It is a lot of code so would take hours to copy and paste it manually.

Thanks for the help.

```
{
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 581,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "def add_trig_slope(data, size = 1, axis = 0, option = 0, random = False, lower_b = -1, upper_b = 2): \n",
    "    \n",
    "    # To make the gradual decline of the fuck you plot\n",
    "    ## sin, cos, tan, sigmoid, other activation functions?\n",
    "    # need to list the option in the doc string\n",
    "    \n",
    "    ## Add a random element\n",
    "    newdata = data.copy()\n",
    "    cols = list(newdata.columns)\n",
    "    funcs = [math.sin, math.cos, math.tan, expit]\n",
    "    func = funcs[option]\n",
    "    if axis == 0:\n",
    "        for col in cols:\n",
    "            newdata.loc[:, col] -= size * (func(cols.index(col)))\n",
    "            if random:\n",
    "                newdata.loc[:,col] -= np.random.uniform(lower_b,upper_b)\n",
    "\n",
    "    elif axis == 1:\n",
    "        for i, node in enumerate(newdata.index):\n",
    "            newdata.loc[node,:] -= size * (func(i))\n",
    "            if random:\n",
    "                newdata.loc[node,:] -= np.random.uniform(lower_b,upper_b)\n",
    "\n",
    "        \n",
    "    return newdata\n",
    "    \n",
    "    "
   ]
```

Comment: This question seems misleading. As far as I can tell this file has not been "converted to .py", it is just a notebook file incorrectly saved with the `.py` extension. Just change the extension back to `.ipynb`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just rename it changing the extension
e.g. for linux/macos

```
mv <file>.py <file>.ipynb
```

or right-click rename for windows and type the full name with the extension

(Since it seems that the contents are .ipynb contents already)

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly. I will accept the answer in 8 minutes when I can - thanks for answering the question so quickly.

Comment: This method does not work for me. The error message when trying to open the jupyter file is as follows:
`Unreadable Notebook: C:\Users\Wei-shan\Desktop\python notebooks\regression-trees\cart_weishan.ipynb NotJSONError('Notebook does not appear to be JSON: \'"""Implementation of the CART algorithm...')`

Comment: The method in the answer only works if you have a notebook that is saved as .py (which is what the question was about), not as a general conversion mechanism from .py to .ipynb

Answer (score 53):

Use p2j to convert Python source code to Jupyter Notebook.

From the command line, run

```
-->pip install p2j
```

then go to the directory where your file is located.
-->( for example-> cd downloads, if the file is in download directory)

then run

```
-->p2j myscript.py
```

This will create a myscript.ipynb file.

Comment: This is not at all efficieent. It has commented all the lines just after the first comment.

Comment: Works pretty well : it converted all "main comments" (i.e. starting with '#' and no leading space) to MarkDown cells, and assigned each function definition to a dedicated cell.

Answer (score 16):

You really should consider using [jupytext](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html)

Run `conda install jupytext`  or `pip install jupytext`

Then do:
`jupytext --set-formats ipynb,py <file>.ipynb`

This will create the .ipynb file and for an additional bonus keep it synchronized to the .py file:

`jupytext --set-formats ipynb,py <file>.ipynb --sync`

This will make sure jupyter keeps the two files in sync when saving from now on...

Last note: If you are a gui person, after running the installation command for jupytext, everything else can be done from the gui as well `File-->jupytext-->pair Notebook with light Script`:
[image]

Comment: I really like what's described from here :) If only it can annotate the file :D Because I'm a Software Engineer building Data Sciences LOL I modularized and containerize everything :D I want to keep both Software and Data Engineers working in harmony :) each on their own world

Comment: Depends what you mean by annotation... I think every cell will be annotated so that it can be reconstructed... E.g. for cell [3], it will be preceded by  #[3] etc.

Comment: Is there a way to use this with Pycharm?

Answer (score 8):

[ipynb-py-convert](https://pypi.org/project/ipynb-py-convert/)

By following below steps you can get .ipynb file

Install "pip install ipynb-py-convert"
Go to the directory where the py file is saved via command prompt
Enter the command

> ipynb-py-convert YourFileName.py YourFilename.ipynb

Eg:. ipynb-py-convert getting-started-with-kaggle-titanic-problem.py getting-started-with-kaggle-titanic-problem.ipynb

Above command will create a python script with the name "YourFileName.ipynb" and as per our example it will create `getting-started-with-kaggle-titanic-problem.ipynb` file

Comment: Works good, converted .py file without problem

Answer (score 4):

Renaming won't work if the py fils were py from the beginning. The easiest way might be to run the following script from PowerShell:

1. Install ipynb-py-convert:

   pip install ipynb-py-convert
2. jump to your directory level

   cd "YOUR_DIRECTORY_PATH"
3. Convert all files recursively (also in all subdirectories):

   foreach ($f in  Get-ChildItem "." -Filter *.py -Recurse){ ipynb-py-convert $f.FullName "$($f.FullName.Substring(0,$f.FullName.Length-3)).ipynb"}

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Install jupytext package (# pip install jupytext)

```
import jupytext
notebook = jupytext.read('example.py')
jupytext.write(notebook, 'example.ipynb', fmt='.ipynb')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to apply the conversion of all the .py files rooted in your project directory , you can run the following command in batch file:

```
for /r %%v in (*.py) do p2j "%%v"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jupytext --to notebook <name_of_script_file>.py
```