# How to run a Spark (python) ETL pipeline on a schedule in Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a DataBricks notebook (Spark - python) that reads from S3 and after doing some ETL work, writes results to S3. Now I want to run this code on a schedule as a `.py` script, not from a notebook. The reason I am looking to run a python script is that it makes the versioning easier

I understand I need to [create a job](https://docs.databricks.com/jobs.html#create-a-job) in Databricks that runs on a schedule. But looks like a Databricks job can only run a `JAR` (scala) or a `notebook`. I don't see a way to run a python script there.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Where is this python script developed? Locally?
If yes, you can have a jenkins pipeline that converts .py script to Ipyhton notebook and writes to DBFS so that it can be scheduled as a regular Python notebook job.

You can do this in your script itself if you want to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292242/converting-to-not-from-ipython-notebook-format

Comment: @Sai no. I was basically writing the ETL in a python notebook in Databricks for testing and analysis purposes. But eventually, I want to take the code out of the notebook to a .py for maintainability and versioning purposes.

Comment: By default DB has version control: https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/github-version-control.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this functionality is not currently available in the Databricks UI, but it is accessible via the REST API. You'll want to use the [SparkPythonTask](https://docs.databricks.com/api/latest/jobs.html#jobssparkpythontask) data structure.

You'll find this example in the official documentation - [Jobs API examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/examples#--jobs-api-examples).

```
curl -n -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d \
'{
  "name": "SparkPi Python job",
  "new_cluster": {
    "spark_version": "7.3.x-scala2.12",
    "node_type_id": "Standard_D3_v2",
    "num_workers": 2
  },
  "spark_python_task": {
    "python_file": "dbfs:/pi.py",
    "parameters": [
      "10"
    ]
  }
}' https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/jobs/create
```

OR

You can execute Jars and Python scripts on Azure Databricks using Data Factory.

**Reference:** [Execute Jars and Python scripts on Azure Databricks using Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/videos/azure-friday-execute-jars-and-python-scripts-on-azure-databricks-using-data-factory/)